# Symfony configuration tree builder

Tags: php, configuration, symfony

I've been trying to make tree builder configuration with Symfony 3 to parse a configuration like that:

```
my_bundle:
    import:
        paths:
            - 'some/path'
            - 'another/path'
```

My TreeBuilder looks like this:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('import')
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('paths')
                    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->defaultValue([])
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

It is basically like two dimensional array config I would like to get as a result. Could you guys help me figure it out?

Expected parsed config:

```
['import' => ['paths' => ['some/path', 'another/path']]]
```

Comment: And what do you get instead?

Comment: `->defaultValue() is not applicable to concrete nodes at path "my_bundle.import.paths"`

Comment: And what kind of behaviour do you want to archive? Why do you apply `cannotBeEmpty` and `defaultValue([])` at the same time? `[]` **is** empty.

Comment: `cannotBeEmpty` is irrelevant at this point. It does even compile as valid configuration tree definition. The thing what I want to achieve is that `paths` array would be under `import` key on root array.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I forgot to prototype the data structure:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('import')
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('paths')
                    ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Comment: Yes, but it could be empty in this case. That's why I asked why did you put `cannotBeEmpty()`

Comment: How the TreeBuilder would look if no config is set to `config.yml`? I mean that the default value would be `['import' => ['paths' => []]]`?

Comment: I believe root node is still required, but import and paths might be empty. But it's just something very easy to be checked once you've got a code